# How to access a window?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, handle

I'm trying to access a specific window using its handle (that is `System.IntPtr` value):

```
        // Getting the process of Visual Studio program
        var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv")[0];

        // Showing the handle we've got, we've no problem
        MessageBox.Show(this, process.MainWindowHandle.ToString());

        // Attempting to get the main window object by its handle
        var wnd = NativeWindow.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);

        // always fails
        if (wnd == null)
            MessageBox.Show("Failed");
        else
            MessageBox.Show(wnd.ToString(), "Yeeeeees!!");
```

I have tried also to access another demo .net winforms application's main window, that I have made for this purpose, (i.e. I run the demo application, and attempted to access its main window by this application), and failed, too, although both the demo and this application are .NET applications. However, this successes:

```
        var process2 = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        MessageBox.Show(this, process2.MainWindowHandle.ToString());

        var wnd2 = NativeWindow.FromHandle(process2.MainWindowHandle);
        if (wnd2 == null)
            MessageBox.Show("Failed");
        else
            MessageBox.Show(wnd2.ToString(), "Yes");
```

I think this works because it is invoked from the same application. So, how can I access some another program's window object by its handle?
I thought it can work using `C\C++` by using header file `<windows.h>` and then using a P\invoke.

If I can't, is there another way to access a window (i.e. rather than using handles)?

===================
**EDIT**

I want to deal with the entire window object and its own controls

Comment: Couldn't you use user32.dll and call FindWindow(null, "Window Title")?

Comment: is that another .NET application windowsforms application ?

Comment: My guess, that first example calling one forms'ui from another thread, and second example from the same thread. Try use BeginInvoke

Comment: Why not use the `System.Windows.Automation` namespace? Its purpose is manipulating the controls of other applications!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then, as Raymond suggested, why don't you try with Automation? Add a console project with references to  `UIAutomationClient` and `UIAutomationTypes`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad");

            var p = Process.Start(pInfo);

            p.WaitForInputIdle();

            AutomationElement installerEditorForm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle);

            // menus
            AutomationElementCollection menuBars = installerEditorForm.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(
                AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.MenuBar));

            var mainMenuItem = menuBars[0];

            AutomationElementCollection menus = mainMenuItem.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(
                AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.MenuItem));

            var fileMenuItem = menus[0];

            ExpandCollapsePattern fileMenuItemOpenPattern = (ExpandCollapsePattern)fileMenuItem.GetCurrentPattern(
                ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern);

            fileMenuItemOpenPattern.Expand();

            AutomationElement fileMenuItemNew = fileMenuItem.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
                new AndCondition(
                    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.MenuItem),
                    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "New")));

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

[reference](http://code.dblock.org/automating-win32-ui-testing-systemwindowsautomation-and-project-white)

Comment: This is not what I want exactly, but it is no problem

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [`NativeWindow.FromHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.fromhandle.aspx) explains why that function always returns `null` for you:

> The handle must already be owned by another NativeWindow in the
>   current process; otherwise, null is returned.

But the window that you are targeting is in a different process. So you simply cannot use `NativeWindow` here. You will have to make do with the window handle as an `IntPtr`.

In your edit you state:

> I want to deal with the entire window object and its own controls

That changes nothing. You can't use `NativeWindow`. You will have to deal with the raw Win32 API.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to access? You can get the title and text of windows in Windows. But you cant get a NativeWindow object of another application. You need to use the windows API to interact with other applications. I once hijacked an object in another app, but did so by knowing its class and discovering a hack to find its Idispatch pointer, you can look into it [here](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=74112&lngWId=1). Below is how to get the title of the foreground window, hope this helps.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using System.Text;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
{
    const int nChars = 256;
    IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    handle = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
    {
        return Buff.ToString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thought I might add, if you're trying to subclass a window of another application, you should take a look at my link above. I believe the only way to do it is using DLL injection and windows hooks, exemplified in my example [here](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=74112&lngWId=1).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get what you're really trying to do but maybe if you try...

```
public class ApiUtils
{
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, ShowWindowCommand nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]

    public static extern int GetForegroundWindow();

    public static void ActiveWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        if ((IntPtr)GetForegroundWindow() != hwnd)
        {
            ShowWindow(hwnd, ShowWindowCommand.ShowMaximized);
        }
    }


}
```

now calling it...

```
Process p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = "someApp.exe"});

ApiUtils.ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, WindowShowStyle.ShowNormal);
```

If not sorry, didn't get the question really well.

Comment: -1 If you don't get the question, and it really looks that way, then it is best to seek clarification through comments. This answer is really not helpful. By the way, I'm trying to help you understand how to provide better answers here rather than do you down.

Comment: Thanks David, clarification first shall I ask for ;)